# z3-solver installed functions not working

Tags: z3py

I installed z3 and the z3-solver components via pip using
`pip install z3` and `pip install z3-solver`
then in my Jupyter notebook I test the following code and error

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-ef7631f40ab0> in <module>
      1 from z3 import *
----> 2 x = Int('x')

NameError: name 'Int' is not defined
```

I do not have any file called z3.py or z3.*

Comment: Maybe you have a local file named `'z3.py'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Installing Both

```
$ pip3 install z3-solver

$ pip3 install z3
```